# How to create tab widget like this picture?

Tags: android

[image]

I want to create a tab widget like this.Would you please tell me how to create a tab like this?If I use rounded image then how to keep space between tabs?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:divider
```

check this out. you can give some color to draw between the tabs. This is xml attribute in tab widget  tag.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html#attr_android:divider